# Execute create table query from column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two select statements which are to create table and insert values into table. How to execute all the queries inside the column at one go? Below is my code and the output:

```
select n.*
into #norm
from specNormalization n 

select n.* 
into #raw
from rawdata n 

select distinct 'CREATE TABLE raw' + c.desttablename + ' (' + STUFF(
             (select ','+QUOTENAME( c.[destfieldname] ) + c.datatype 
             from #norm c
     group by c.destfieldname, c.datatype 
                 for xml path ('')),1,1,'') as createTableSQL 

select distinct 'INSERT INTO raw' + c.desttablename + 
             select d.contents 
             from #raw d join #norm c on d.tablename = c.desttablename
     as insertTableSQL
```

rawdata table

| desttablename | destfieldname | datatype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rawtable | SbjNum | int |
| rawtable | Surveyor | nvarchar(20) |
| rawtable | Location | nvarchar(20) |
| rawtable2 | SbjNum | int |
| rawtable2 | Name | nvarchar(20) |
| rawtable2 | Address | nvarchar(20) |

specnomalization table

| tablename | destfieldname | contents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rawtable | SbjNum | 1 |
| rawtable | Surveyor | Alex |
| rawtable | Location | Georgia |
| rawtable2 | SbjNum | 1 |
| rawtable2 | Name | Sandra |
| rawtable2 | Address | Portland |

| createTableSQL |
| --- |
| CREATE TABLE rawtable ([Sbjnum])int, ([Surveyor])nvarchar(200), ([Location])nvarchar(200) |
| CREATE TABLE rawtable2 ([Sbjnum])int, ([Name])nvarchar(200), ([Address])nvarchar(200) |

| insertTableSQL |
| --- |
| INSERT INTO rawtable SELECT [Sbjnum], [Surveyor], [Location] from #raw |
| INSERT INTO rawtable2 SELECT [Sbjnum], [Name], [Address] from #raw |

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248368/discussion-on-question-by-sriram-nr-execute-create-table-query-from-column-in-sq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the create query by using stuff. Since you would have multiple tables so you have to group by the query to return multiple table names and it's columns separately. So the result query you can set into a variable and can execute by using

```
EXEC sp_executesql
```

So you can easily create as much as tables based on your table data.
The following query will help you to create multiple tables. This you can optimize if needed, but this will give you the insight to do the same for inserting values to the tables respectively.

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(MAX) = ( SELECT ' CREATE TABLE '+ desttablename +' (' + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + sn.[destfieldname] + ' ' +datatype
                               FROM  dbo.specNormalization As sn
                               ORDER BY sn.destfieldname
                               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') + ' )'
FROM dbo.specNormalization as P2
GROUP BY P2.desttablename  FOR XML PATH('') )

-- Uncomment to see the created query
-- SELECT @sql

-- To execute the created query. This will create the tables with column and datatype
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Try to generate `SELECT .. INTO .. FROM` to create and populate a target table. Kind of

```
    SELECT cast([Sbjnum] as int) [Sbjnum], cast([Surveyor] as nvarchar(200)) [Surveyor], cast([Location] as nvarchar(200)) [Location]
      INTO rawtable
    FROM #raw
```

If the source types are the same as target, skip `cast` functions. Can't  tell what is the query to generate it as no sample data are provided.

Comment: The tables are created dynamically so i cant use into for this

Comment: I am just looking to execute the queries within the two columns

Comment: Use a cursor to iterate over the table containing 2 columns of sql text to be executed dynamically.

Comment: Yes this is what i was thinking to do. But not sure. Will check it out